# Sending out alerts when a certain option is chosen on a Sharepoint form

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint list, with two different views when creating a item in that list. Let us call these views, "regular user view" and "Approver user view" and the two views differ because one of the fields is hidden in the "regular user view" and is shown in the other view. Let us call this hidden form field "Approved or Decline". The particular group that the field is shown for, will come in after the regular user creates a new item and either changes the value of the "Approved or Decline" form field to either Approved or Declined based on if that person wants to accept or decline the request. How do I set up a alert, so if the "approver" declines a request, a notification is sent to the person that initially made that request?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a SharePoint Workflow configured with SharePoint designer.  Here is an overview of workflows: https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/sharepoint-workflow-fundamentals

You would need to have the workflows automatically run when an item is created or modified and inside you would detect when the "Aprroved or Decline" field == "Declined" and in that case send an email to the original creator of the item.